# If an image is transparent background, does it mean every pixel has 0 in alpha?

Tags: image, image-processing, png

I am wondering if an image is transparent background, does it mean every pixel's alpha value is 0? Or some are 0, some not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 100% transparent pixel has an alpha of 0. A 10% opaque pixel (translucent) has an alpha of 10. An image with a mix of transparency has a mix of alpha values.